# Внутренние и вложенные классы

Tags: java, ооп

Внутренние и вложенные классы — это не одно и тоже.

В чем разница, и когда принципиально нужно использовать один, а когда другой?

Comment: @LEQADA я так понимаю, речь о nested class и inner class, и это разные вещи

Comment: @Etki, да, никогда не был силён в терминологии. Прочитал и понял, что речь о inner и nested

Comment: да все верно речь о inner и nested

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Статические вложенные классы**, не имеют доступа к нестатическим полям и методам обрамляющего класса. Поведение точно такое же, как у статических методов класса. Доступ к нестатическим полям и методам может осуществляться только через ссылку на экземпляр обрамляющего класса.

Но static nested классы имеют доступ к любым статическим методам внешнего класса, в том числе и к приватным.

```
public class Mememe {
   private static int m_AccessableInt; // доступно в StaticNestedMememe
   private int m_NotAccessableInt;     // не доступно в StaticNestedMememe
   [...]

   public static class StaticNestedMememe {
      [...]
   }
}
```

Применение? Например, если вложенный класс имеет смысл только в контексте обрамляющего класса.

Так же многие используют такие классы для реализации паттерна [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Экземпляр такого класса нужно создавать, используя имя обрамляющего класса:

```
Mememe.StaticNestedMememe nestedObject = new Mememe.StaticNestedMememe();
```

**Внутренние классы** бывают трёх типов:

- локальные классы (local classes);
- анонимные классы (anonymous classes);
- внутренние классы-члены (member inner classes).

**Локальные классы** определяются внутри блока кода.

```
public class Mememe { 
    public void calc(String requestPath) { 
        class Сalculator{ 
             int calc() { return 0; } 
        }
    }
}
```

Локальные классы имеют доступ к полям и методам обрамляющего класса. Локальные классы:

- видны только в пределах блока, в котором объявлены;
- не могут быть объявлены как `private`, `public`, `protected` или
  `static`;
- не могут иметь внутри себя статических объявлений; исключением являются константы (`static final`);

**Анонимный класс** (anonymous class) - это локальный класс без имени.

Типичный пример - реализация `Runnable`:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ...
        }
    }).start();
```

Основное ограничение при использовании анонимных классов - это невозможность описания конструктора, так как класс не имеет имени.

**Внутренние классы-члены** ассоциируются не с самим внешним классом, а с его экземпляром. При этом они имеют доступ ко всем его полям и методам. Например:

```
public class OuterClass { 
    public void method() { ... } 

    public class InnerClass { 
        public void method() { ... } 

        public void anotherMethod() { 
            method(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

`InnerClass` имеет доступ в членам класса `OuterClass`, как видно на примере метода `anotherMethod`, который вызывает метод `method`.

Создать такой класс можно так:

```
OuterClass outer = new OuterClass(); 
OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass = outer.new InnerClass();
```

Comment: Отличный ответ )

Comment: *Экземпляр такого класса нужно создавать, используя имя обрамляющего класса* - импортируется ровно так же, как и всё остальное.

Comment: Круто, спасибо!

Comment: это лучшее объяснение из того что я читал, спасибо!

Comment: Вроде как ошибка, нужно так (в самой последней строке): OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass = outer.new InnerClass ();

Comment: @cosmic_M спасибо, поправил (:

Answer (score 3):

Внутренний (inner):

- Требует объект родительского класса для создания, жестко связан с ним.
- Объект имеет доступ к приватным полям родительского объекта

Вложенный (nested):

- Не требует объект родительского класса для создания
- Не имеет доступа к приватным полям объектов родительского класса, но имеет доступ к приватным полям родительского класса.

Код:

```
public class Example {

    public static int si = 0;
    private static int psi = 0;
    public final Inner inner;
    public int i = 0;
    private int pi = 0;

    public Example() {
        inner = new Inner();
    }

    public static class Nested {

        int e;

        public Nested() {
            e = Example.psi;
            e = Example.si;
            // а вот так нельзя
//            e = Example.this.pi;
//            e = Example.this.i;
        }

    }

    public class Inner {
        int e;

        public Inner() {
            e = Example.psi;
            e = Example.si;
            e = Example.this.pi;
            e = Example.this.i;
        }
    }

}

class ExampleTwo {
    // Nested можно сразу
    Example.Nested nested = new Example.Nested();

    Example.Inner inner;
    {
    // так нельзя, нужен объект Example
//        inner = new Example.Inner();
        // а так можно
        Example example = new Example();
        inner = example.inner;
    }

}
```