# Inner и Nested Classes Java - в чем отличие?

Tags: java, классы

Есть ли отличия между статическим внутренним и статическим вложенным классом? 
И когда лучше использовать внутренний и вложенный классы?

Comment: так лан, не буду париться, просто сделаю то чего ты почему-то не сделал, https://goo.gl/qnHTW3 вот хороший ответ, первый в гугле

Comment: ОТВЕТ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481167/%D0%92%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B

Comment: @UlaLa не ссылку кидайте, а голосуйте за закрытие.

Comment: @AntonDanilov не ссылку кидайте, а голосуйте за закрытие.

Comment: @AntonDanilov сам удалит, не будь вредным

Comment: ребят, дайте разобраться. прошу не спешить с закрытием вопроса

Comment: @Ula La  В чём проблема? И я не вредный, а полезный..... закончим  пикироовки

Comment: @AntonDanilov, видишь человек ещё до конца не разобрался, успеешь закрыть, не волнуйся. В конце концов тут людям помогают

Comment: Я ничего не улаляю ... bye