# Нужно ли использовать только композицию и агрегацию при создании вложенного класса?

Tags: java, ооп

Нестатические вложенные классы нужны для тех случаев, когда класс создается как часть другого класса(чтобы много классов со схожими названиями не создавать, aka carWheel,bicycleWheel и тд)(эстетика) или когда класс много где использует переменные внешнего класса(тех. часть). Более они от обычных классов ничем не отличаются(кроме запрета на создание static переменных и static методов).
На основании этих данных всплывает вопрос - что я теряю при использовании композиции и агрегации:

```
class Bicycle{
    Wheel wheel;
    Bicycle(int степеньНакачкиКолес/*и другие переменные*/){
        wheel = new Wheel(степеньНакачкиКолес);
        /*и другие переменные*/
    }
    Bicycle(/*другие переменные*/){
        wheel = new Wheel();
        /*другие переменные*/
    }
    class Wheel{
        int степеньНакачкиКолес;
        Wheel(int степеньНакачкиКолес){
            this.степеньНакачкиКолес = степеньНакачкиКолес;
        }
        Wheel(){
            степеньНакачкиКолес=0;
        }
        void weGotDamage(){
            toStopEveryThing();//мы имеем доступ к переменным и методам внешнего класса!
        }
    }
    void toStopEveryThing(){
        //code
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bicycle bicycle = new Bicycle(500);
        bicycle.wheel.weGotDamage();//вызываем метод объекта wheel toStopEveryThing();
    }
}
```

По сравнении с этой реализацией:

```
class Bicycle2{
    Bicycle2(){}
    class Wheel{
        int степеньНакачкиКолес;
        Wheel(int степеньНакачкиКолес){
            this.степеньНакачкиКолес = степеньНакачкиКолес;
        }
        Wheel(){
            степеньНакачкиКолес=0;
        }
        void weGotDamage(){
            toStopEveryThing();//мы имеем доступ к переменным и методам внешнего класса!
        }
    }
    void toStopEveryThing(){
        //code
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Bicycle2 bicycle = new Bicycle2();
        Bicycle2.Wheel wheel = bicycle.new Wheel(500);
        wheel.weGotDamage();//Оно свяжется с bicycle и вызовет метод toStopEveryThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Внутренние и вложенные классы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481167/%d0%92%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b)

Comment: @Grundy Что это значит: "Внутренние классы-члены ассоциируются не с самим внешним классом, а с его экземпляром.". С технической точки зрения? Если так, то зачем создавать их отдельно, если мы можем использовать композицию и агрегацию? Ведь так будет логичнее. Тех особенности я то знаю(и написал для полноты картины), но мне интересен именно этот вопрос.

Comment: Это лишь краткий обзор возможностей. А я о проектировании говорю(с использованием композиции и агрегации). Это не вопрос-дубликат

Comment: Перефразированный вопрос непонятен. И на него нельзя дать однозначный ответ, одни скажут что нужно только их использовать, другие скажут что нужно не только их использовать, третьи скажут что что вообще не надо агрегацию и композицию использовать

Comment: @Grundy так если кто-то скажет, почему это нужно использовать или не нужно, то он подтвердит это примерами. Давайте вообще запретим все вопросы про проектирование классов. Ведь один скажет, что данный метод проектирования неэффективен, другой, что эффективен. Ну разумеется каждый будет приводить свои доводы. Не вижу проблемы.

Comment: или не подтвердит, от этого неоднозначность вопроса не меняется.

Comment: Что может быть непонятного? Это прямой вопрос - стоит ли использовать ТОЛЬКО композицию и агрегацию при создании вложенного класса. Если человек знает, что я теряю какой-то функционал или подвергаю свой код ошибкам, то он это скажет. Это такой же по типу вопрос, как "какие опасности и преимущества использования наследования?". На него можно прямо ответить, как и на мой.

Comment: Это плохо сформулированный вопрос. "Стоит ли использовать?" - вопрос, который зависит от условий. И писать реферат на триста листов когда стоит и когда не стоит - это не формат для so, ведь so - для конкретных вопросов. Приведите свой пример кода, где вы не понимаете какой выбор сделать, поясните свои аргументы - и тогда это будет более-менее вопрос для so, потому что это будет конкретная проблема. В текущем виде вопрос плох, потому что вы просто вбросили код, но не обозначили проблему этого, в чём она? Он работает? В других вариантах работает? Какие критерии говорят, что это плохой код?

Comment: @AK ну что, теперь вообще не задавать вопросы про теорию? Почему я не могу вопросить - какой подход какими недостатками обладает? Вот скажите - почему на одном форуме мне ответили(https://javatalks.ru/topics/54485), а на другом шлют нахер, мол переделывай вопрос, некорректен? Что ж за коммюнити то такое...

Comment: Обрати внимание, что вопрос по твоей ссылке отличается от текущего вопроса, как минимум вторым примером кода. А так как вопросы отличаются, странно удивляться что и реакция на них разная.

Comment: @Grundy От первоначального вопроса тот отличается только по-другому заданным вопросом(результирующим) и вторым блоком. Даже измененный вопрос может подвергнуться этой критике: "И на него нельзя дать однозначный ответ, одни скажут что нужно только их использовать, другие скажут что нужно не только их использовать, третьи скажут что что вообще не надо агрегацию и композицию использовать "

Comment: @Miron, я именно это и сказал :-) _что я теряю при использовании композиции и агрегации: ... По сравнении с этой реализацией:_ - по сути это и сделало бы вопрос здесь более конкретным.

Comment: Наличием main в классе он отличается.

Comment: @Grundy Хорошо, десять раз подумаю, прежде чем задавать вопрос

Comment: @Miron, именно об этом и написано в справке: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Псс, откроем его, или как? Я уже изменил

Comment: Да, в такой форме намного лучше. Снял минус, проголосовал за переоткрытие.